# how to select multiple image from asset or drawable

Tags: android

i m implementing simple demo.. but i m stuck because i don't know how to select multiple images from drawable folder. i've seen so many solution but this is all about to select image from gallary.

here is my image
[image]

i m implementing lock screen demo, what i need is select 4 image sequentially  that user set that image as a password, how can i do this

help me please,
Thank you

Comment: i just want to know how to select multiple image from drawable folder, after that i will implement this thing..

Comment: Do you know, `int imageId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("your_image_name", drawable, getPackageName());` and then `image.setImageResource(imageId);`

Comment: i know about this, try to understand what i need.. i need to pick multiple image like we are selecting multiple image from gallary

Comment: is it like you want to show images existing in your drawable folder and then allow multiple selection on them ?

Comment: yes.. i just want to select multiple image run time

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's easier to help you if you post some specific code that shows the problem.

Comment: sorry.. i dont know the code of what i want to implement.. how can i post code

Comment: try following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189883/creating-image-gallery-using-drawable-images-in-res-folder

Comment: @DhavalkumarSolanki i am trying..